# How can I remap ctrl+c to ctrl+c in Autohotkey when the buttons (Win, Ctrl, Alt) are blocked in scancode map registry?

Tags: autohotkey

I have my keyoard CTRL button blocked in scancode map registry, but in the other side I need to enable the combination ctrl+c and ctrl+v for the administrator, So I wrote this part of code but it's not working:

^c::

Send, ^c

return

What do you think I can do to resolve this issue?

FYI : I've tried also to add $ before ^c to be able to send the same combination

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `CTRL` button blocked, `^c::` will not be detected. Try an alternative such as this.....

```
!c:: ; This is ALT C
Keywait, %A_ThisHotkey% ; Waits for the above hotkey to be released. 
Send, ^c
return
```